# How to install requirements for a target defined in meta.yaml

Tags: python, conda, conda-build

I have `meta.yaml` which has a section looking a little bit like this:

```
requirements:
  build:
    - pylint 2.7.*
  run:
    - sqlalchemy 1.3.*
```

How can I install just requirements needed for `build`? Is there something like `conda install --target build`?

Answer (score 0):

By default, building creates a temporary `_build` environment that gets deleted immediately after. There is a `--bootstrap` flag that let's one specify an existing environment, but I'm not sure that's helpful here. Instead, you likely want something like

```bash
conda-build --build-only --dirty RECIPE_PATH
```

which will run the build, creating the temporary `_build` environment, and skip the auto-deletion. You can then debug on that `_build` environment (activate by path).

See [the `conda-build` command's documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/commands/conda-build.html).